# GCP VPC SC Rules for all projects under a folder

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc

I am trying to set Ingress and Egress Rules for a service perimeter.

Currently have setup rules based on service accounts and resources(Projects).

I am also trying to see if I want to create rules at Folder Level.

Example-:
ORG->
DEV->
ProjectA
ProjectB
QA->
ProjectC
ProjectD

I have a service perimeter set at ProjectA & ProjectB.
Is there a way to create egress rule allowing target as ANY Project under folder "QA" instead of listing each project in the rule?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `\\"\*\\"` on the resources to `egressTo` all resources or use the folder `"folders/123456"`. See the following YAML as example

```
- egressTo:
    operations:
    - serviceName: service-name
      methodSelectors:
      - method: method
      *OR*
      - permission: permission
    resources: \"*\"
  egressFrom:
    identityType: ANY_IDENTITY | ANY_USER_ACCOUNT | ANY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT
    *OR*
    identities:
    - serviceAccount:service-account
    - user:user-account
```

Also, there are some limitations on using the service control based on this [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/supported-products#restricted_vip_supported_services)